# Deploy artifacts in lastsuccesful build jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, archive, symlink, artifacts

I have a jenkins (pipeline) build. My lastsuccesful build of my pipeline:

```
+ ls -ltrah /srv/jenkins/jobs/xx-IB/lastSuccessful/
total 7.5M
-rw-r--r--. 1 jenkins jenkins  442 Dec 19 11:27 3.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 jenkins jenkins   64 Dec 19 11:27 4.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 jenkins jenkins 3.6K Dec 19 11:27 8.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 jenkins jenkins    0 Dec 19 11:27 9.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 jenkins jenkins 4.6K Dec 19 11:27 10.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 jenkins jenkins    0 Dec 19 11:27 11.log
```

But it does not contain symlinks to my created artifacts.
How can I access my created artifacts from my lastsuccesful build so I can access the artifacts from here (symlinks): `/srv/jenkins/jobs/jobname/lastSuccessful/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Archive the artifacts in `post` after every `stage`

```
stage('Build Debug') {
    steps {
        dir('project/embsw') {
            sh 'mingw32-make.exe makefile=Makefile clean'
            sh 'mingw32-make.exe makefile=Makefile debug'
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            archive "project/embsw/debug/*"
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will archive everything which in present inside directory `project/embsw/debug/`.
So I would recommend to archive in every `stage` if you have any artifact to archive and avoid having a separate stage for archiving.
This is the advantage of using `Pipeline`, you can archive in every stage not like old `Jenkins` config method where you archive in the last or `post build action`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
stage ('Archive artifact') {
            steps {
                script {
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/**/xxx-*-SNAPSHOT.xx'
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This should be the expected answer